# Destroy div's smoothly with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I have been looking around for this but I haven't found it, I have 2 divs in table tds:

```
 __________ __________
|         | |         |
|  Div 1  | |  Div 2  |
|         | |         |
|_________| |_________|
```

I was to decrease the width of div1 while fading away the contents and destroy it at the end, then I want to make it reappear right to div2 so I can css different contents.

Comment: that is some great html.

Comment: You should create an example, maybe with [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so everybody can edit your solution to get your excpected result (and to help you).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Kktvy/ here we go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `animate` function.

```
$('#div1').stop().animate({
        width:0,
        opacity:0
    }, 1000, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
```

This firstly calls `stop()` to stop any existing animation. It then animates the width and opacity of the element to 0 in 1000ms. It finally calls `remove()` on the `#div1` after the animation has completed.

If you want it to reappear immediately after then calling `remove()` is unnecessary. You'll want to use `appendTo()` in this case:

```
...
   }, 1000, function() {
       $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());
       /* Remember that the width and opacity are still 0 here, so you'll need to revert the animation when re-displaying it */
   });
```

This assumes that your HTML markup is something along the lines of:

```
<div>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NQzj4/1/).

Comment: Thanks! They are both in td elements though and div1 contains other elements which I would not like to delete manually.